# Calculating the Surface Area of an Egg Using 29 Sample Points on Outline

Tags: calculus, integration

I am calculating the surface area of an egg. To do so, I have taken a picture of the egg and have plotted 29 points on the outline of the egg based on the image. The egg was calibrated to a scale of 1cm=1 unit, and a axis was placed on the middle of the egg, with (0,0) being the centre of the egg. With my 29 points plotted on the half portion of the egg above the x axis, how do I use rules such as the Riemann Sum or the Trapezium Rule to calculate the surface area of the egg? Each of my points are 0.25units apart on the x axis, and have varying y values based on the height of the egg. My teacher told me that it is possible to find the surface area of the egg using the Riemann Sum, but based on my research, the Riemann Sum approximates the area underneath the curve. I do not understand how this would be helpful for me in terms of calculating the surface area, because by revolving this area under the curve around the y axis, I would only be getting the volume of the egg which is not the aim of my investigation.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose your data are $(x_k,y_k)$ with $k=1,\ldots,n$

The surface of the solid of revolution around $x$ axis generated by a curve $f(x)$ in the interval $[a,b]$ is
$$A_x=2\pi \int _{a}^{b}f(x){\sqrt {1+{\big (}f'(x){\big )}^{2}}}\,dx$$
With $n$ discrete data we can get the surface area of revolution around $x$-axis with the formula
$$A_x=2\pi\sum_{k=1}^n \left[y_k\sqrt{1+\left(\Delta_k y/\Delta_k x\right)^2}\right]$$
If you need more help, send the actual data

Suppose you have a set of data $Y=(y_k),1\le k \le 21$ and $X=(x_k)=k$
$$Y=\{0,4.359,6.000,7.141,8.000,8.660,9.165,9.539,9.798,9.950,10.00,9.950,9.798,9.539,9.165,8.660,8.000,7.141,6.000,4.359$$
Differences are
$$\Delta y_k=\{4.359,1.64,1.14,0.86,0.66,0.50,0.37,0.26,0.15,0.05,-0.05,-0.15,-0.26,-0.37,-0.50,-0.66,-0.86,-1.14,-1.64,-4.359\}$$
and in this case, as $\Delta x_k =1$ for all $k$ we have
$$\left(\frac{\Delta y_k}{\Delta x_k}\right)^2=\{19.00,2.69,1.30,0.74,0.44,0.25,0.14,0.07,0.023,0.003,0.003,0.023,0.07,0.14,0.25,0.44,0.74,1.30,2.69,19.00\}$$
add $1$ and take square root
$$\sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\Delta y_k}{\Delta x_k}\right)^2}=\{4.472,1.922,1.518,1.318,1.198,1.120,1.068,1.033,1.011,1.0013,1.0013,1.011,1.033,1.068,1.120,1.198,1.318,1.518,1.922,4.472\}$$
Now take $Y'=(y_k),1\le k \le 21$ and $X=(x_k)=k$
$$Y'=\{4.359,6.000,7.141,8.000,8.660,9.165,9.539,9.798,9.950,10.00,9.950,9.798,9.539,9.165,8.660,8.000,7.141,6.000,4.359\}$$
which is $Y$ less the first component. This is necessary because differences are $20$, while data are $21$

Now perform the dot product $$Y\cdot \sqrt{1+\left(\frac{\Delta y_k}{\Delta x_k}\right)^2}=199$$

$S=2\pi\cdot 199=1251$ is the approximated surface.

The data were not random. They were the coordinates of $21$ points on a semicircle and the actual surface is the surface of a sphere with radius $10$ that is $S=4\pi\cdot 10^2\approx 1257$.

Comment: Yes please! Where should I share you my data set? Also, can you explain each individual component in the formula, because I need to be able to show how it works in my investigation. Thanks so much!

Comment: @MarcusCHAN Send your data *here*. $(x_k,y_k)$ are the coordinates of the points. $\Delta_k y$ and $\Delta_k x$ are the differences, i.e. $\Delta_4 y=y_4-y_3$. It is the discrete version of the derivative

Comment: How did you derive it the formula? I'm writing a paper and I don't understand how to explain where the formula comes from.

Comment: Also, how do I call it the formula? Is it the trapezium rule but revolved around the x axis?

Comment: @MarcusCHAN To do more precisely estimation, you need first numerical differentiation https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_differentiation and then numerical integration https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Numerical_integration#Methods_for_one-dimensional_integrals

Comment: @MarcusCHAN Numerical integration can be done as I did it or interpolation with a polynomial and then integrating the polynomial. My formula is a "self-made" approximation formula which works fine, but has no reference.

Comment: @MarcusCHAN I edited my answer to include an example. Hope this helps